# Limit of a sequence of functionals $F_n : C([0,1]) \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the Banach space $C([0,1])$ with $\| . \|_{\infty}$ maximum norm. Consider the linear functional $F_{n} : C([0,1]) \to \mathbb{R}$, $ F_{n} (f) = f(1) - f\big(\frac{2n - 2}{2n - 1}\big) + f\big(\frac{2n-3}{2n-1}\big) - f\big(\frac{2n-4}{2n-1}\big) + ... - f(0)$

Show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(f) = \frac{f(0)-f(1)}{2}$.

I already proved that $C^1([0,1])$ is dense in $C([0,1])$ using Weierstrass Stone theorem for a previous item in this same exercise. But I don't see how can I prove this limit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n( \color{red}{f} ) = \frac{f(1) \color{red}{-} f(0)}{2} \tag{*}$$

is what really you mean, it is easy to prove the convergence for $f \in C^1([0, 1])$. Indeed, by the mean value theorem, for each $n$ and $k$, there exists $\xi_k = \xi_{f,n,k} \in (\frac{2k}{2n-1}, \frac{2k+1}{2n-1})$ such that

$$ f\left(\frac{2k+1}{2n-1}\right) - f\left(\frac{2k}{2n-1}\right) = f'(\xi_k) \frac{1}{2n-1}. $$

Thus it follows that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( f\left(\frac{2k+1}{2n-1}\right) - f\left(\frac{2k}{2n-1}\right) \right)
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f'(\xi_k) \frac{1}{2n-1} \\
&\xrightarrow[\ n\to\infty \ ]{}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} f'(x) \, dx
= \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{2}.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, there are continuous functions for which $\text{(*)}$ is not true. For instance, let $f$ be the [*Cantor-Lebesgue function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). Then

$$ F_{(3^n+1)/2}(f) = \sum_{k=0}^{(3^n-1)/2} \left( f\left(\frac{2k+1}{3^n}\right) - f\left(\frac{2k}{3^n}\right) \right) = 1 $$

since the Cantor set $C$ is contained in $\bigcup_{k=0}^{(3^n-1)/2} [ \frac{2k+1}{3^n}, \frac{2k}{3^n} ]$ and $f$ increases only on $C$. So we have

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} F_n(f) = 1 \neq \frac{1}{2} = \frac{f(1) - f(0)}{2}. $$

Comment: It is tempting to take  polynomials $g_n$ where $\max_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-g_n(x)|=O(n^{-2})$ as $n\to \infty.$  So $F_n(f)=(f(1)-f(0))/2+O(n^{-1})+A(n)$ where $A(n)=O(n^{-3}\max_{x\in [0,1]}|g''_n(x)|).$  But at this point we get stuck, as we cannot refute your counter-example.